# CORS setup for Amazon Cloudfront caching

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-cloudfront

I have set up CDN Caching using W3C Total cache WP plugin and Amazon Cloudfront.

Having [such an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJVNh.png) with single font [here](http://wp.pkotula.com/), while all other resources are loaded correctly

And here is the part of `.htaccess` which should fix it, but doesn't

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://cdn.wp.pkotula.com/"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

And here is the server response.

> Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>   Content-Length:   14180    Connection:    close    Server:    nginx    Date:  Thu, 03
>   Nov 2016 11:05:15 GMT  Last-Modified: Tue, 01 Nov 2016 10:45:38 GMT
>   ETag: "58187252-3764"  Accept-Ranges: bytes    X-Cache:   Miss from
>   cloudfront     Via:   1.1 db022c33630ee831434a6faa2414eaac.cloudfront.net
>   (CloudFront)
>   X-Amz-Cf-Id:  g38ytC9610MhGeRELPxY7Jz3MDgBfvSAxLmTsuBm50dHZMs24V9Y3g==

Cloudfront and DNS are also configured to work with CNAME `cdn.wp.pkotula.com`

Comment: the error is about `http://wp.pkotula.com` not `http://cdn.wp.pkotula.com/` have you tried allowing access to the root domain (no cdn prefix)?